# What is the purpose of 'Captures' tab in Android Studio 2.3.3?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.3

I had noted a new tab '**Captures**' on the left side of the Android Studio 2.3.3.
 For me it is seem to be empty.

- What is **Captures** meant for?

Please refer the documentation explaining on **Captures in Android Studio**.

Comment: Have you looked up the documention for it? Surely they'll be a section outlining its use.

Comment: couldn't find anything related to 'captures' tab in the documentation 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're monitoring memory usage in the Memory Monitor included in Android Monitor you can, at the same time, dump a snapshot of the Java heap to an Android-specific Heap/CPU Profiling (**HPROF**) file. The HPROF Viewer displays classes, instances of each class, and a reference tree to help you track memory usage and find memory leaks. HPROF is a binary heap dump format originally supported by J2SE.

After you do a heap dump, Android Studio automatically stores it so you can view it again.  "Captures" is where you see these saved HPROF dumps.

You can also see captured view layout etc there as well.

There isn't an answer to this in the built-in help.  However, according to the [release notes from 2015](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio12preview2available), it is a "*view which shows the various performance data files you've collected*".

You can learn more about Captures in the [documentation about HPROF](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-hprof.html).